# Dumb notation question about bra-ket

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, linear-algebra

Is $\langle b | A^T | a \rangle = \langle a | A | b \rangle ^ *$ where $^*$denotes complex conjugation?

**Edit**

Maybe I should add some more info here and clear things up. First, $A$ is not necessarily Hermitian. Second, since $|a\rangle ^{\dagger} = \langle a|$, it might be better to rewrite the above expression as

$$
\langle b|A^T|a\rangle = \langle b|(A^*)^{\dagger}|a\rangle = 
(\langle a|A^*|b\rangle)^*.
$$

Would this be a better way of writing it?

Comment: I corrected my answer - the operator is not necessarily Hermitian conjugate, but we are talking here about Hermitian conjugation vs. transposition.

Comment: You don't need the outer brackets to indicate that transpose applies to the whole expression. However, while your new equation is correct, the first one is still not.

Comment: Only the hermitian conjugate (and not the transpose and conjugation) have a real meaning in a Hilbert space. The other two depend on the basis you choose to define them.

Answer (score 0):

Hermitian conjugation of a matrix is defined as trasposition plus complex conjugation:
$$
(A^\dagger)_{ba} = A_{ab}^*.
$$
In Bra-ket notation:
$$
\langle b|A^\dagger|a\rangle = \langle a|A|b\rangle^* .
$$
The equation in the OP contains only transposition on the left, but transpositiona nd complex conjugation on the right.

**Remark**
@Brick has correctly pointed out in a comment that $*$ here applies to the whole expression rather than only to $|b\rangle$ (which would be meaningless, although one would sometimes encounter notation $|b^*\rangle$, where $b^*$ is a quantum number used alongside $b$ - e.g., rather common when dealing with coherent states; also $|b\rangle^\dagger =\langle b|$).

Comment: This assumes, of course, that the $*$ on the right is understood to apply to the whole expression rather than just $|b\rangle$.  That's probably what was meant by the OP, but since the question is about notation it might be worth emphasizing here.

Comment: @Brick thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Brick You cannot complex conjugate an individual ket vector/state. If you're suggesting that it would correspond to obtaining the corresponding bra-vector, that would be incoherent. The star must apply to the entire amplitude.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan in some cases one uses $|b^*\rangle$ notation, sinc ethere are different quantum numbers, $b$, and $b^*$ - e.g., when using coherent states. So clarification doesn't hurt. Of course, this is not conjugation of a state, as you correctly pointed out.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I did not mean to suggest it was proper. I was only pointing out that the question inherently asks what the notation means and therefore someone coming along (presumably because they are confused) might mistake it.

Comment: Yeah okay, those are fair points.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I totally agree with you, as has been discussed in the comments above.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I  now clarified it.

Comment: I will now remove my comments, to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 0):

The expression
\begin{align}
\langle b | A^T | a \rangle = (\langle a | A | b \rangle) ^ *
\end{align}
is in general true if the states $\vert a \rangle$, $\vert b \rangle$ are real. A proof of this can be seen through:
\begin{align}
(\langle b | A^T | a \rangle)^{\dagger} 
&= \langle a | (A^T)^{\dagger} | b \rangle \\
&= \langle a | A^* | b \rangle \\
&= (\langle a^* | A | b^* \rangle)^* \\
\end{align}